# How I can optimize my LINQ query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

I have written following LINQ query to return list of Groups and then iterating list separately.

I only need list of Groups of User with specific email.

I am sure this might not be the right away.

Can i re-write it in a better way (performance-wise) ?

```
var groups = _context.Users.Where(m => m.Email == email)
                           .Include(g => g.Customer)
                           .ThenInclude(r => r.CustomerGroups)
                           .ThenInclude(t => t.Group)
                           .First().Customer.CustomerGroups;

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    var s = group.Group;
    //do something
}
```

Comment: What data does your logic actually need? Does it need information about the customers belonging to a group? If so, does it need the user details like email?

Comment: @AdamSimon I only need list of Groups of User with specific email.

Comment: Please explain what are the issues with your current query and what really do you mean by "optimize", the "not right" or "better" way etc. For instance, are you getting an exception? Or getting incorrect result, or it is slow, or loads too much data, or doesn't load the data you need etc.

Comment: @Bart Ok, I think my answer covers now every possible aspect of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need just *CustomerGroup* entities with the related *Group* entity (as I interpret your clarification in the comment section) it's inefficient to fetch other related entities (*User* and *Customer*). You can make EF to fetch only the entities you are interested in like this:

```
var groups = 
(
    from user in _context.Users
    from customerGroup in user.Customer.CustomerGroups
    where user.Email == email
    select customerGroup
).Include(cg => cg.Group);
```

Or when *CustomerGroup* stores no relevant data, just relationships:

```
var groups = 
(
    from user in _context.Users
    from customerGroup in user.Customer.CustomerGroups
    where user.Email == email
    select customerGroup.Group
);
```

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for the suggestions. The side note about Include and redundancy was removed as it turned out that it doesn't apply to EF Core.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

That is make query on `CustomerGroups` table so You don't need Include `Customer` and `CustomerGroups` .

```
var customerGroups = _context.CustomerGroups.Where(m => m.Customer.User.Email == email)
                    .Include(t => t.Group).
                     Select(s=> new CustomerGroupModel {
                           A= s.A,
                           B= s.B,
                           …
                           Group = s.Group
                     }).ToList();
```

Or

```
  var customerGroups = _context.Customer.Where(m => m.User.Email == email)
                .Include(r => r.CustomerGroups).ThenInclude(t => t.Group).
                 Select(s=> new CustomerGroupModel {
                       A= s.CustomerGroups.A,
                       B= s.CustomerGroups.B,
                       …
                       Group = s.CustomerGroups.Group
                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you also add explanation why your answer is more optimized?

Comment: Explanation is not for me, take a look [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for better qualified answers. An answer could be right but not qualified at all. The code you write may be not understandable for OP. So I suggest you to edit your answer and add explanation it.